# aggregation to get a counting list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How do I get a counting list for all chapter codes for this data?

```
[
    {
        catId: 101,
        chapter: [
            {
                id: '1234',
                title: 'Title 1',
                code: 'X12.3'
            },
            {
                id: 'abcd',
                title: 'Title 2',
                code: 'X12.4'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        catId: 102,
        chapter: [
            {
                id: 'abcd',
                title: 'Title 2',
                code: 'X12.4'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For this simple example I would expect something like

```
2 - X12.4
1 - X12.3
```

I think I need an aggregation like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$code',
      Datasets: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before grouping, you first need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the chapter array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$chapter"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$chapter.code",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This will give the following result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "X12.4",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "X12.3",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D1jIIlio_Aq)

Comment: Perfectly. Would it be technically possible to add some data from a second collection in the same aggregation? The meaning of the code is stored in another collection, so the result could be `{ "_id": "X12.4", "count": 2, "name": "Something" }` if the second collection has data like `{ "code": "X12.4", "name": "Something" }. Or do I have to do a second query?

Comment: @user3142695 I guess it would be possible with lookup. I advise you try first to learn better, if you can't solve, you may consider asking a new question.

Comment: Ok, just one question for this topic: Can I combine $unwind with $match for the aggregation? I just want to get some specific documents.

Comment: @user3142695 yes you can apply the match anywhere you want, [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/feH7kAn8-oW)